# Sharepoint 2010 outgoing emails encoding issue

Tags: workflow, encoding

I have several workflows which send email notifications. Some of the outgoing emails have very strange titles, like the following:

> Скоро срок СЃдачи поручРµния СоздатСЊ расписаниРµ по дисциплинам
>
> Задачи - Настроить работу блога на  =?utf-8?Q?=D0=BA=D0=BE=D1=80=‏

Both sentences are utf-8 encoded, in russian. Some of the characters inside the sentence were replaced with incorrect ones, I have no idea what is the reason of it. Is there any way to investigate or fix it?

Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://vintentou.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/encoding-of-sender-name-using-sputility-sendemail/
This solution relates to sender name. But if It works, It can be helpful for your situation too.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. The thing is that I was using sharepoint designer to create a workflow, which is sending emails. So there is no c# code.